# Switch parts of a string

Tags: c#, string

I've got a list of strings that look like this

```
String s = "Top-0001-V[5]"
```

and I need to switch the parts to this Pattern:

```
String sF = "0001-Top-V-[5]"
```

I already tried to split them at "-" and then adding them, but the problem is it's a really long line of code, is there a way of doing this in an easy way, or do i have to split it all the way up and add it back togehther?

Comment: What is your split pattern _exactly_? I couldn't get it.

Comment: `Really long line of code?` - how long? why so? why do you consider it too long?

Comment: I think it's `<1>-<2>-<3>[<4>]`, where `<1>` should be swapped with `<2>` and between `<3>` and `[<4>]` should be a `-`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This might do the trick for you

```
var items = s.Split('-');
items[items.Length - 1] =  items[items.Length - 1].Replace("[","-[");
string x = String.Format("{0}-{1}-{2}", items[1], items[0], items[2]);
```

The output will be

> 0001-Top-V-[5]

You can also use `String.Substring` if the format of the string is common because `String.Substring` Retrieves a substring from this instance. The substring starts at a specified character position and has a specified length.

Comment: I would add `.Replace("[", "-[")` at the end of the string format to get `0001-Top-V-[5]`.

Comment: Its pleasure @WinnieTopGun. Happy Coding :)

Answer (score 3):

A Regex might help:

```
var r = new Regex("(Top)-(\\d+)-(V)\\[(\\d+)\\]");
string result = r.Replace(myInout, "$2-$1-$3-[$4]")
```